# MySQL How to prevent string truncation

Tags: mysql, sql, string, aggregate-functions

I have a SELECT statement in MySQL 5.6 which uses the group_concat function to create a delimited string from many database rows in a table.  The length of the string should be several thousand characters in length, but MySQL seems to be automatically truncating the resulting string at 2048 characters.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the value of parameter `group_concat_max_len`. If you wanted to do that at session-level, that would be:

```
set session group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```